# Single Sign On using Identity Server 4

Tags: cookies, single-sign-on, identityserver4

I have a question about the SSO flow.

Let's say we have 2 MVC applications as clients and an authentication provider

Client 1 has a cookie lifetime of 40 minutes.

Client 2 has a cookie lifetime of 10 minutes (maybe it's more strict for security reasons)

The expiration for the cookies is sliding, e.g. if a user logs in at 12:00 the cookie will expire in 12:40, however if the user makes a call to a page at 12:05 the expiration will subsequently be at 12:45

Now, what we want to do is implement SSO using Identity Server 4

- User tries to login to Client A
- User is redirected to Identity Server
- User logs in on IS - User is redirected back to Client A with tokens

then

- User tries to login on Client B
- User is redirected on Identity Server
- Identity Server cookie exists
- User is redirected back to Client B with tokens

What is the correct approach regarding the Identity Server cookie expiration?

For example, upon logging in to the second client, the Identity Server cookie is already set to be 40 minutes long from the previous login. This is a problem due to the need of the second client for a cookie expiration time of 10 minutes.

Comment: I'd suggest not trying to line them up but instead enforce and rules you might have about how recently they signed in interactively in the client - e.g. use the `max_age` parameter and validate the `auth_time` claim.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will have a look.

Comment: I have a question. Is it correct to set for the client 40m (same with the client cookie lifetime) refresh token lifetime (I know is is short for refresh token) and when it is expires to redirect the user on Identity Server using the max_age parameter? or there is a more automated/correct way to do  it? I have two clients: dotnet core client and mvcclient with owin.